# Cannot find the way to make .text() works with its own value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if there is a way to use the reference to the object itself, `$(this)`, inside the `.text()` function, in a way to increase its value plus 1.

Example in pseudo-code:

```
jQuery("div").text(+$(this).text() + 1);
```

Thank you in advance for any help.
Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a handler function:

```
jQuery("div").text(function(i, str) {
    // 'this' can be used here as well

    return +str + 1;
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `+` before `str` be removed? It otherwise returns `NaN`. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/uxMFr/1/

Comment: @JoshC No, it should not, since otherwise increment will work as concatenation for valid text content: http://jsfiddle.net/uxMFr/2/.

Comment: My bad - didn't see that in the OP. I just thought it was suppose to append a `1`.

Comment: @user3139803 In CoffeeScript the callback should look like that: http://jsfiddle.net/9NKWU/3/.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the context right:

```
jQuery("div").each(function(){
  $(this).text($(this).text() + 1); 
})
```

Example:
http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/09190b68af60ef7fae48bab63980d1d1